# Is there a word for people having done something bad and earned himself a bad reputation?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do people call someone having done something bad and earned him(her)self a really bad name, making family members and friends disgraced? (He or she might have been a good person before the bad deed was exposed. But now no one likes him(her). Everybody that used to be friendly wants to catch every opportunity to humiliate him(her) or give him(her) a smash on the face)

What about "StreetRat"?

Any better or more accurate suggestions?

Comment: Probably not.  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Street+Rat

Comment: “Street Rat” means homeless child? Does "There are many street rats in the town" equal “There are many homeless children in the town.” ?  That sounds weird to me.

Comment: It is not weird.It is exactly what it is.

Comment: I'm sure "street rat" has many localized connotations, but UD is probably your best bet at finding a "commonly understood" meaning.

Comment: I suspect many people would interpret "street rat" to include young "feral" kids who are often out on the street (and possibly up to mischief) even when they are not technically "homeless".

Comment: [Black sheep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/black_sheep).

Comment: *one having done something bad and earned a really bad name, making family members and friends disgraced* might have fitted Andrew's *black sheep* but why must *street rat* mean any kind of miscreant?

*Everybody… wants… every opportunity to humiliate him or give him a smash on the face* pushes your idea way past either, though, and on through *renegade* or *outlaw*, too.

To me *pariah* might fit the bill but even that seems a mite mild.

Answer (score 2):

**disgraced** would seem to fit:
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disgraced

> Many feel that the mayor has **disgraced** the town government  by accepting personal favours from local businesspeople.